# How good is gnash as a replacement for flash?

Tags: adobe-flash, multimedia

Fedora suggests the Gnash plugin as a replacement for the Flash plugin and I am seriously considering it.

My question is: how good is the Gnash plugin as a replacement for the Flash plugin?

In my case, I'm not interested in anything advanced, just being able to watch youtube videos.

Comment: Best way to find out is to try it yourself and see whether it is suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

On the [Gnash Web page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/) it's write that

> Gnash is based on GameSWF, and supports most SWF v7 features and some SWF v8 and v9.
>
> SWF v10 is not supported by GNU Gnash.

But if you check on the [Adobe Web page](http://get.adobe.com/fr/flashplayer/) we are presently at the 11.2 version. This version will be the last one released for GNU/Linux OS, but it still support more features than Gnash.

Comment: Okay. But is it enough to play videos on youtube?

Comment: You might want to check youtube.com/html5, and you get rid of Flash on Youtube altogether.

Comment: I was reading something about it, but it says that not every video will play with the html5 player. So I think I'll subscribe to youtube's test with html5 and install Gnash for the videos that don't support it yet. Thanks.

Comment: VIdeo that aren't working with HTML5 are very old videos. I never get one since 3 years now.